# several indicators not visible on panel in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: evernote

I installed everpad on my ubuntu 12.10 (which was a upgraded from ubuntu 12.04). But now I am not able to run it, creat any new notes. Also, its indicator icon is not visible in panel. System monitor shows that the application is running. When I click on everpad icon in launcher nothing happens. However I can run everpad settings. Please help

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't know evernote, but maybe you can check the systray-whitelist in dconf-editor or try to reinstall evernote first.
If isn't installed, just install dconf-editor from software center or do

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

After that lanuch dconf-editor from dash/terminal and go to:

com --> canonical --> unity --> panel.
There you can edit the applications show in systray. These are my settings:
['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Wine', 'Update-notifier', 'Skype']
Just try to add evernote to this line like this:
['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Wine', 'Update-notifier', 'Skype', 'Evernote']

Hope this helps.
Maybe someone here have another/better idea...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually installed everpad - an note taking client - ubuntu version of evernote. I did what you said. Added command line 'everpad %eu'. But no luck. I have noticed that it is there in the startup program list also, and starts with system restart. Is it a bug?

Comment: Hi, Problem is partially solved. Added 'everpad' instead of 'everpad %eu'. I am able to open new notes now. Not able to see everpad indicator icon in panel though!